# Is it possible to 'partially' protect a variabile?

Tags: programming

Please, consider a variable initialized at the beginning of a program:

```
$myVar = {};
Protect[$myVar];
```

and the only two functions allowed to change it:

```
myVarAdd[arg_] := Module[{},
   Unprotect[$myVar];
   AppendTo[$myVar, arg];
   Protect[$myVar];
 ];

myVarReset[arg___] := Module[{},
   Unprotect[$myVar];
   $myVar = {};
   Protect[$myVar];
 ];
```

**Edit**

The complication is that the `Protect` - `Unprotect` trick doesn't really 
guarantee the safety of `$myVar`, simply makes unintended alterations less probable, because it's possible, in any case, to unprotect and alter it some where else in the code.

A more sturdy protection would be, as an example, to intercept modifications, and inform the user if made outside `myVarAdd` and `myVarReset`, in a fashion similar to what illustrated in `tutorial/InterceptingTheCreationOfNewSymbols`:

*"Sometimes it is useful to "intercept" the process of **creating** a new symbol."*

could became, in the    circumstance we are talking about,

*"Sometimes it is useful to "intercept" the process of **changing** the value of a symbol."*

Is it feasible ?

**Note**
I have rephrased the question, hoping to make it clearer, but at the core it's meaning remains the same. No doubt: it's totally my fault, and I'm the only one to blame, but really I can't understand what is unclear. Please, can you provide a brief explanation ?

Comment: What other functions would go to the length of unprotecting a variable before modifying it? Have you found any built-ins that would do that? Perhaps you might be interested in alternative methods of "protecting" variables discussed in this language guide: [Package Bulletproofing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PackageBulletproofing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! In my real program `myVar` is `$appStack`, a global variable, used for debugging purposes. When some functions are called, they append their own names to it, but changes to  `$appStack` are not permitted aside from this case: that's the reason why I want impose some restrictions.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you would be the sole author of any code capable of making those changes :-) so you should be able to control any modifications. Could you show an example of a case where you suspect that an unwanted modification might take place?

Comment: _Ego prudentiam numquam neglego ..._ Better safe than sorry : 
a lethal, wrong, copy-and-paste, a typing error late in night, an undocumented recondite feature, a bug, a brand new sad discovery when the reactor's core is already melted ... ;-).

Comment: Do you need to protect the variable from *yourself*? If you want to refer to it read-only in the rest of your code and the functions `myVarAdd` and `myVarReset` to be the only means of knowingly manipulating it, why not use a getter/setter approach known from other programming languages? Simply hide it from yourself, give it an obscure private context and/or name you will never refer to directly (easy to check using full text search) and only return its *value* (or its copy) upon request – should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I'm trying to protect the variables from everything, yes, including me. I don't know about "getter/setter approach" and I'm googling about it; please, can you provide a simple example in Mathematica ? Aside the field within my question arose, curbing objects to some authorized manipulator seems to me a deep programming challenge in itself.

Comment: So you want a warning each time your variable is changed? As a question / feature, that woul make sense. Ultimately however, it seems to me that no matter how elaborate your protective setup, unless you chisel your code in stone (or similar ROM), it will always be susceptible to (inadvertent or not) change by the programmer.

Comment: Yes, such a warning could add an additional protection.

Comment: From your description of the kind error you want protection from, I don't think you need to use `Protect`/`Unprotect`. Rather, I suggest you put the variable in the `private` context within a package that defines the getter and setter functions for the variable. It is still possible to change such a variable by assignment, but hardly by accident or mistake. You would have to write something like ``myPkg`private`myvar`` to reference it directly.

Comment: @mitochondrial: To clarify, a getter is a function that simply returns the variable's value. Like `myVar[] := $myVar`. (Actually, in Mathematica it's practical to do just `myVar := $myVar` and then protect `myVar`, no need for the brackets.) No operation done with `myVar` can then change `$myVar` itself. Similarly, a setter is a function whose purpose is to change the value of the internal variable in a controlled way (perhaps putting on some restrictions, performing validity checks, calling side effects, making sure other things that depend on the variable stay synchronized).

Comment: In your case I would say: ``MyPackage`Private`$myVar = {}; myVar := MyPackage`Private`$myVar; Protect[myVar]; myVarAdd[arg_] := AppendTo[MyPackage`Private`$myVar, arg]; Protect[myVarAdd];`` etc. As far as protecting the variable itself goes, there's nothing your package could do and a malicious programmer couldn't. If you want to make it harder for people to find the name of your hidden variable, make the accessory functions `ReadProtected` and `Locked` (the latter so that the user can't un-ReadProtect them). But they can still guess using `Contexts[]` and `Names[]`.

Comment: Usually (in C++, Java and similar) getter and setter functions are called like `getX` and `setX` for a variable `x`, hence the names.